# Delete an Item on Listview but this doesnt deleted from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I use this method to delete an Item on my SQLite database:

```
public void deleteItem(String item){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.beginTransaction();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ITEMS_COLUMN + " =?",  new String[] {item});
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    db.close();
}
```

And this to my ListView:

```
String nameString = (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)).toString();
Log.d("itemtodelete", nameString);
db.deleteItem(nameString);
magicAdapter.remove(nameString);
magicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is that when i delete an item on my `listview` the item disappears but when I re-open it the item is still there, because this doesn't remove from the database.
I 'll try to explain this with images :

[image: I add an item]

[image: Here it is]

[image: I delete this]

[image: Bye bye Item]

[image: Re-open the list]

[image: Here it is again!]

Answer (score 1):

This means that there is some problem with the deleting from the db. Just replace 2nd line in your deleteItem() with

```
int x = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ITEMS_COLUMN + " =?",  new String[] {item}
Log.d("deletedItem", x);
```

Here `x` would be the number of rows deleted. Check the value of x after deleting, it should be greater than 0 if the deletion was successful. If it is not then that means the query is wrong and we would need the database schema for correcting it. From your `ListView` implementation code, its clear that your `nameString` itself is wrong. You are adding the whole `Item` in the arraylist and passing to the adapter. And when you fetch the item in the `onItemClick` dialog, you are using this code

```
 String nameString = (arg0
                                            .getItemAtPosition(arg2))
                                            .toString();
```

Here `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)` would return an Item object. You will have to do something like this.

```
Item tempItem=(Item)items.get(arg2);
String nameString=tempItem.getName();
```

where `getName()` would return the name of the item.

Comment: deletedItem 0 So this is the problem!

Comment: But i cant do this 
Item tempItem=(Item)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
ClassCast exception!

Answer (score 0):

The change that I did:

```java
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String nameString = (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)).toString();

    Log.d("itemtodelete", nameString);

    db.deleteItem(nameString);

    magicAdapter.remove(nameString);
    magicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String nameString = (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)).toString();
    String nameStringData = nameString.substring(6,
    nameString.indexOf("Priority Level:") - 1);
    Log.d("itemtodelete", nameStringData);
    db.deleteItem(nameStringData);
    magicAdapter.remove(nameString);

    magicAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you have a better suggestion please post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is the problem.

deletedItem = 0 on logCat so that's my database:

```
public class DatabaseHolder extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ItemsList";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Items";
    private static final String ITEMS_COLUMN = "items_name";
    private static final String PRIORITY_COLUMN = "Priority";
    private static final String ID_COLUMN = "Items";

    private static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static String QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + ID_COLUMN + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ITEMS_COLUMN
            + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + PRIORITY_COLUMN + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public DatabaseHolder(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(QUERY);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

    // Sharer!

    public void addItem(String item_name, String priority) {

        if (!duplicate(item_name)) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ITEMS_COLUMN, item_name);
            values.put(PRIORITY_COLUMN, priority);

            db.beginTransaction();
            db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean duplicate(String name) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, ITEMS_COLUMN + " =?",
                new String[] { name }, null, null, null);
        int temp = c.getCount();
        c.close();
        db.close();
        if (temp > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getAllItems() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ArrayList<Item> item = new ArrayList<Item>();

        db.beginTransaction();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { this.ITEMS_COLUMN,
                this.PRIORITY_COLUMN }, null, null, null, null, PRIORITY_COLUMN
                + " DESC");

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            Item itemTemp = new Item(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ITEMS_COLUMN)), new Level(
                    Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(PRIORITY_COLUMN)))));
            item.add(itemTemp);

        }

        cursor.close();
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
        return item;

    }

    public void deleteItem(String item){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int x = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ITEMS_COLUMN + " =?",  new String[] {item});
        Log.d("deletedItem", String.valueOf(x) );
        db.beginTransaction();

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ITEMS_COLUMN + " =?",  new String[] {item});

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

        db.endTransaction();

        db.close();


    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, delete the next delete line from your method. Only one deletion is required. Secondly check the value of `itemtobedeleted` and check your database just before deleting. Check the rows in the database i that item exists. To check your db take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321246/how-can-i-read-my-database-from-ddms

Comment: The query seems correct, there must be some silly mistake. Like check if the db string and the string you are sending are perfectly equal, i.e. case sensitive.

Comment: I know how to check my database but thanks for the link! I check it before create this topic so my problem is sure in my Database.

Comment: As i said, check the db value and the value that you are sending. Make sure they are completely equal. Since they are strings make sure they are case sensitive equal.

Comment: I send the var nameString, I don't know what this var includes because the user choose from listview. I just add some images to get my problem easier

Comment: Could you check the value of `nameString`? Check if `nameString` exists in the database!

Comment: Ok thanks! This is the problem i dont send the name of the item "Milk" but i send "Item: Milk"
I will try to fix this! Thanks again mate!